# Show one of two styles depending on action/controller-pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have 10 controllers with about 5 actions each, i.e. summing up to about 40 view templates.

I have two completely different styles for the application, one for admin-area and one for users-area.

What would we be the simplest way to inform the views which one of the two styles to apply?

The admin-area and users-area are not simply seperated by the controllers, it's per action-basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, it's on a per-action, the quick and dirty way to do this is:

Create a helper method which returns a boolean based on if the user stylesheet is needed:

```
def use_user_stylesheet?
  valid_actions = %w(# array of actions which need user styles)
  if valid_actions.include? params[:action]
end
```

You can then use it to wrap your two style sheets in your `layouts/application.html.erb` file.

So:

```
<% if use_user_stylesheet? %>
  # <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'your_user_stylesheet' %>
<% else %>
  # <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'your_admin_stylesheet' %>
<% end %>
```